# Can't push local production.sqlite3 to remote heroku postgresql DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I'm mobile devices programmer and I'm a newbie in DB, web, server programming and this problem make me sick :(

I've dug all day long for this situation, and no answer solve my problem.

I have production.sqlite3 in my Ruby on Rails project, and this was in AWS server using sqlite3 DB in production mode.

Now I uploaded this application to heroku using postgresql DB with no data(empty), changing sqlite3 -> postgresql in production mode.

I want to transfer data in production.sqlite3 to empty remove postgresql DB.

How can I do that? I couldn't get the concept how I achieve this.

1) local sqlite3 -> remote empty postgresql DB directly ?

2) local sqlite3 -> local postgresql (migrate) -> remote empty postgresql DB ?

I installed postgresql92 (because of heroku remote postgresql version) via macports,

so the path is  '/opt/local/lib/postgresql92'.

I tried

- pg:transfer
- psql
- pg_ctl

and still have no idea to do this. please help me solve this situation.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use the same database in all environments. I can't post comments yet to ask for clarification so I'll try to answer your question. Sorry if I get too basic.

If you need to transfer data from an SQLite to a PostgreSQL database you'll have to do this manually with a tool such as https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps. You will have to setup the local PostgreSQL database and import the data from the SQL database. Then, you can push the data to heroku using:

```
db:push [<database_url>] # push a local database into the app's remote database
```

Add the PostgreSQL gem to the Gemfile

```
gem 'pg'
```

Example database.yml file for using PostgreSQL

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_development
  pool: 5


test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_test
  pool: 5


production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_production
  pool: 5
```

Next, you'll need to create the database

```
rake db:create:all
```

Make sure after all this that the rails development database is psql (run rails db)

That's how you ensure rails is using psql.

Comment: I heard heroku db:push and db:pull is deprecated. That why I'm look for other ways.

Comment: No, actually previous SQlite3 DB is for production and used about 1 year and that why I really want to transfer this DB to new one.